# PHP curl cannot read a page

Tags: php, curl

PHP curl at our localhost works fine but not on any other server

Here is the code

```
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux i686; rv:13.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/13.0.1" );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://50.7.243.50:8054/played.html');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER ,0);    
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);  
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_TIMEOUT,120);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS,20);


$data = curl_exec ($ch);
if ($data == false)
    echo "CURL ERROR : ".curl_error($ch)."<br>";
curl_close ($ch);
```

even if we do this

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://50.7.243.50/played.html');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PORT, 8054);
```

it shows error **couldn't connect to host**

Any help is appreciated....

Comment: I'd look into firewalls if I were you.

Comment: ICY 404 Resource Not Found icy-notice1:
SHOUTcast Distributed Network Audio Server/Linux v1.9.8
icy-notice2:The resource requested was not found

Comment: The link `http://50.7.243.50:8054/` is being downloaded for past minute, and still keeps on downloading(over 2 MB)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this code, i have tested and working.

```
$html = "http://50.7.243.50:8054/played.html";
$header = array();
$header[] = 'Accept: text/xml,application/xml,application/xhtml+xml,text/html;q=0.9,text/plain;q=0.8,image/png,*/*;q=0.5';
$header[] = 'Cache-Control: max-age=0';
$header[] = 'Connection: keep-alive';
$header[] = 'Keep-Alive: 300';
$header[] = 'Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7';
$header[] = 'Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5';
$header[] = 'Pragma: ';
$ch = curl_init();

$proxy_ip = '122.72.112.148';
$proxy_port = 80;

 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYPORT, $proxy_port);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYTYPE, 'HTTP');
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, $proxy_ip);


curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $html);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_PORT , 8054);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.0; en-US; rv:1.9.0.11) Gecko/2009060215 Firefox/3.0.11 (.NET CLR 3.5.30729)');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, true); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, '');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 20);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close ($ch);
echo $result;
```

Comment: Where can I get more proxies ? - great answer btw.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code :

```
$html = "http://50.7.243.50:8054/played.html";
$header = array();
$header[] = 'Accept: text/xml,application/xml,application/xhtml+xml,text/html;q=0.9,text/plain;q=0.8,image/png,*/*;q=0.5';
$header[] = 'Cache-Control: max-age=0';
$header[] = 'Connection: keep-alive';
$header[] = 'Keep-Alive: 300';
$header[] = 'Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7';
$header[] = 'Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5';
$header[] = 'Pragma: ';
$ch = curl_init();


curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $html);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.0; en-US; rv:1.9.0.11) Gecko/2009060215 Firefox/3.0.11 (.NET CLR 3.5.30729)');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, true); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, '');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 20);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close ($ch);
echo $result;
```